# how to store PE32+ preferred imageBase address?

Tags: c++

I have this PE loader that works really fine with 32bit PEs but with x64 ones it can't allocate the 0X0000000140000000 preferred base address since it only reads it as 0X40000000.

Here is how I allocate that address:

```
DWORD hdr_image_base = p_NT_HDR->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
char* ImageBase = (char*)VirtualAlloc((void*)hdr_image_base, size_of_image, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

but when I hardcode the address It works just fine:

```
char* ImageBase = (char*)VirtualAlloc((void*)0X140000000, size_of_image, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

**Is DWORD not enough to store the address?**

this reallocation code is stripping some variable-length somewhere since it still works with 32 but not with x64:

```
//this is how much we shifted the ImageBase
    DWORD_PTR delta_VA_reloc = (reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(ImageBase)) - p_NT_HDR->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
    
    // if there is a relocation table, and we actually shitfted the ImageBase
    if (data_directory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress != 0 && delta_VA_reloc != 0) {
        printf("\n[*] The relocated address is not the prefered address, started relocating\n");
        //calculate the relocation table address
        IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION* p_reloc = (IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION*)(ImageBase + data_directory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress);
        
        //once again, a null terminated array
        while (p_reloc->VirtualAddress != 0) {
            // how many relocations in this block
            // ie the total size, minus the size of the "header", divided by 2 (those are words, so 2 bytes for each)
            //std::cout << sizeof(WORD) << "\n"; sizeof word is 2
            DWORD size = (p_reloc->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);

            // the first relocation element in the block, right after the header (using pointer arithmetic again)
            WORD* reloc = (WORD*)(p_reloc + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                
                //type is the first 4 bits of the relocation word
                int type = reloc[i] >> 12;

                // offset is the last 12 bits
                unsigned long long int offset = reloc[i] & 0x0fff;
                //printf("--------------- %#llx\n", offset);

                //this is the address we are going to change
                DWORD* change_addr = (DWORD*)(ImageBase + p_reloc->VirtualAddress + offset);

                // there is only one type used that needs to make a change
                // When you relocate you should look if the flag HIGHT_LOW is active for PE32 and DIR64 for PE32+
                switch (type) {
                case IMAGE_REL_BASED_HIGHLOW://for x86
                    *change_addr += delta_VA_reloc;
                    break;
                case IMAGE_REL_BASED_DIR64://for x64
                    *change_addr += delta_VA_reloc;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

            // switch to the next relocation block, based on the size
            p_reloc = (IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION*)((reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(p_reloc)) + p_reloc->SizeOfBlock);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DWORD` has the same size as `void*` and as `uintptr_t` as long as your code is being compiled for x86. Addressing is diff when it comes to x64. Pointers are 8 bytes, not 4 bytes. That's why `uintptr_t`, `void*` or any type* is 8 bytes under x64, and 4 under 64.

However when it comes to work with the PE format, use regular pointer arithmetic. This means, cast your base pointer (in this case the module pointer) to `char*` and go from that.

Comment: I changed DWORD to unsigned long long int and it worked but now I need to replace that (char*) with something equivalent and bigger.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev ah ok It worked now by using (char*)

Comment: I'm glad you made it.

Comment: not yet I still have to figure out why the reallocation code doesn't work well. let me add the code to the post

Comment: I've tried to make data types bigger but still not working